# POST requests to GoDaddy host time out frequently

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, web-hosting, timeout, godaddy

I wrote a C# application to POST data to a script on my GoDaddy shared Linux webserver. The applications makes 100 requests in a loop, and WITHOUT FAIL, the first request ALWAYS times out. The remaining 99 succeed. The total process takes about 45 seconds. Webserver is located in the US, I'm in Singapore.

A little troubleshooting, and it seems that requests that immediately follow a request succeed. But if I make a single request every 5 min, they all fail.

I ran the same script on another webserver (non-GoDaddy, located in Singapore), and not only did it succeed all 100 times, it completed in about half the time (21 seconds). The time difference might be due to the geographical proximity.

I ran a trace route on my GoDaddy host, and this is what I get every single time:

```
  1     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.148.67.2
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.148.64.3
  3    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.148.65.5
  4    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.66.3.29
  5    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.33.1.6
  6    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.33.0.6
  7     1 ms     3 ms     1 ms  203.202.234.194
  8     1 ms    <1 ms     1 ms  10.33.8.130
  9     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  vlan33-fe3-18.br01.sin02.pccwbtn.net [63.218.165
.181]
 10   266 ms   228 ms   219 ms  te8-3.ccr02.sjc03.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.11.
161]
 11   294 ms   208 ms   210 ms  te2-2.ccr02.sjc01.atlas.cogentco.com [66.28.4.77
]
 12   174 ms   174 ms   174 ms  te0-3-0-2.ccr22.lax01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54
.2.149]
 13   185 ms   185 ms   186 ms  te8-7.ccr01.phx02.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.80.
206]
 14   187 ms   187 ms   187 ms  38.104.116.166
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

It always fails after bouncing off `38.104.116.166`.

Failed requests happen when the request is made Singapore, or even the US, so it cannot be a firewall/router problem on client-side.

In short, I am thoroughly stumped, GoDaddy customer care isn't the greatest when you have a shared host with them, and I cannot diagnose where the problem is.

Is the problem at GoDaddy's side, and can/should I put some pressure on them to figure it out.
Also, why is it that only the first request fails, and all that follow succeed? 
I'm not very well versed with the internal workings of a web-server, but is it something like the server goes to 'sleep' and the first request serves as a ping waking it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Shared* is probably your problem here.  I would want to know what else is going on on that server.

If it were my server, I'd be running a `tcpdump` on it while making the request that times out.  If that looked fine I'd be using `strace` on Apache.

It *could* be a network thing but that's less likely.

If you can't do any of that because it's a shared host, it might be time to tell your boss you need at least a VPS.

Answer (score 0):

If you have traffic on your site, I would recommend you to purchase VPS or dedicated hosting. You will build your own server and you arrange everything. :)

Comment: as of now, we're still in the early development and test phase and barely have any traffic at all. Maybe a megabyte a day. We intended to go dedicated once he go live, but it seems we might have to do that sooner now